# Update Meteor Leaderboard with own data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've changed the meteor example leaderboard into a voting app. I have some documents with an array and in this array there are 6 values. The sum of this 6 values works fine, but not updating and showing the values in my app.

The values are only updating, if I click on them. The problem is, that I get the booknames  (it's a voting app for books) from the "selected_books" variable (previously selected_players), but I don't know how I can get the book names.

By the way: _id are the book names. 
I will give you some code snippets and hope, somebody have a solution.

**This is a document from my database:**

```
{
    _id: "A Dance With Dragons: Part 1",
    isbn: 9780007466061,
    flag: 20130901,
    score20130714: [1,2,3,4,5,0],
}
```

**parts of my html file:**

```
<template name="voting">
    ...
    <div class="span5">
        {{#each books}}
            {{> book}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    ...
</template> 

<template name="book">
    <div class="book {{selected}}">
        <span class="name">{{_id}}</span>
        <span class="totalscore">{{totalscore}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

**and parts of my Javascript file:**

```
Template.voting.books = function () {
    var total = 0;
    var book = Session.get("selected_book");

    Books.find({_id:book}).map(function(doc) {
        for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
            total += parseInt(doc.score20130714[i], 10);
        }
    });
    Books.update({_id:book}, {$set: {totalscore: total}});

    return Books.find({flag: 20130901}, {sort: {totalscore: -1, _id: 1}});
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't update data in the helper where you fetch it! Use a second helper for aggregating information or a transform for modifying data items. Example:

```
Template.voting.books = function() {
    return Books.find({}, {sort: {totalscore: -1, _id: 1}});
};

Template.books.totalscore = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
        total += this.score[i];
    }
    return total;
};
```

As a side note, **DO NOT USE** the construct `for (i=0; i<6; i++)`, it's deadly. **Always** declare your index variables: `for (var i=0; i<6; i++)`.